# Pyside6/Qt6 crash in MacOS

Tags: macos, pyside

The following program opens a window with a button that displays which version of PySide is in use. If you click the button, the program displays Wikipedia's home page.

It works fine on PySide 6.3.

On PySide 6.4, it works fine, UNLESS you maximise the window before pushing the button. If you do that, it segfaults.

I'm running Python 3.9 on MacOS Monterey.

```
import PySide6 as qt
import PySide6.QtWidgets as qtw
import PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets as qtweb

app = qtw.QApplication([])
def showWeb():
    stack.setCurrentWidget(web)
    web.setUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org")
button = qtw.QPushButton(qt.__version__)
button.clicked.connect(showWeb)
web = qtweb.QWebEngineView()
stack = qtw.QStackedWidget()
stack.layout().addWidget(qtw.QWidget())
stack.layout().addWidget(web)
window = qtw.QWidget()
window.setLayout(qtw.QVBoxLayout())
window.layout().addWidget(button)
window.layout().addWidget(stack)
window.resize(400, 400)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

The error message on the zsh terminal looks like this:

```
zsh: segmentation fault  python3 segfault.py
[... my command prompt ...] % [67231:259:1105/160207.214403:ERROR:mach_port_rendezvous.cc(310)] bootstrap_look_up org.chromium.Chromium.MachPortRendezvousServer.1: Permission denied (1100)
[67231:259:1105/160207.214737:ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(226)] Mach rendezvous failed, terminating process (parent died?)
```

Comment: Can you try to run the program in a terminal so that you can see if it provides a further traceback? Also note that you don't need to access the layout of a QStackedWidget, just use `stack.addWidget()` directly.

Comment: I am running it in a terminal. The error message looks like this: segfault % [67231:259:1105/160207.214403:ERROR:mach_port_rendezvous.cc(310)] bootstrap_look_up org.chromium.Chromium.MachPortRendezvousServer.1: Permission denied (1100)
[67231:259:1105/160207.214737:ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(226)] Mach rendezvous failed, terminating process (parent died?)

Comment: Add the traceback to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem

The solution: Disabling Python's garbage collection

```
import gc
gc.disable()
```